# Are control sequences the same number in every encoding?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding

I am writing a parser, and the original spec states:

> The file header ends with the control sequence <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd>

They do not specify which encode the header is written in (could be latin1, utf8, windows-1252,...), so I wonder whether the sequence the same number in every language.

It appears to be the case, that it always correspond to decimal **26** or the hexa **1A**

It would be good to know in a more general way, whether this is for all sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, ASCII is assumed. For/if ASCII, especially if you say "Ctrl-Z" corresponds to binary representation/"codepoint" dec 26 hex 1A, this would be the SUB (substitute) sequence.

Other alternatives of the extended character sets/encodings wouldn't apply here, because if dec 26 in ASCII, it's within the first/lower 7 bits of the byte (dec 0-126 of 255 total). The 8th bit then was used to toggle all the previous codepoints/patterns once more and gain/use the other half, the other remaining 127 codepoints from dec 128-255. The idea here is that the extended character sets usually share/retain the lower ASCII codepoints/mappings (also for backward compatibility), but introduce their own special characters in the higher codepoint bit-patterns/range 128-255. And there's then many different ones of this type, trying to support more writing scripts of the world with such custom extended code sets. Like Windows-1252 which is an European mix, ISO-8859-1 for German, ISO-8859-15 which is identical but only adds the Euro currency symbol, code page 437 for IBM DOS shapes to use characters for drawing a TUI on the console (this, for example, has a different mapping at it's code points for what is the control sequences in ASCII), and so on. The problem obviously is, there's a lot of these:

- each only gains 128 more characters
- you can't combine/load/apply any two of them at the same time (if characters would be needed from multiple different code sets)
- each application has to know (or be told) beforehand in which code set a file was saved in order to interpret/display/map the correct character rendering/symbols on the screen for these byte patterns, and if the user or a tool/app applies and saves the wrong code set to save its character renderings while not recognizing that, because the source was previously created/saved with a different code set, some characters didn't appear with the intended original renderings, now the file is "corrupt" because some bytes were stored under the assumption they would be rendered with code set A and some under the assumption they're for code set B, and can't apply both as there's also no mechanism in these flat dumb plain-text files on some old, memory-short DOS file systems to tell which part of a file is for which code-set, the characters can never be rendered correctly and it can be difficult work or impossible to retroactively guess + repair what the desired interpretation/rendering was for the binary pattern in a byte
- no hope to get anywhere with only 127 more characters added on top of ASCII when it comes to Chinese etc.

So then the improvement was to not use the 8th bit for these stupid code pages, but instead use it as a marker that, if set, it's an indication that another byte is following (UTF-8), hence expanding the amount of code-points greatly. This can even be repeated with the next, subsequent byte. But, it's optional. If the character is within the 7-bit ASCII codepoints, then UTF-8 does not need to set the 8th bit and add another byte.

Also means, the extended code pages and UTF-8 cannot be mixed (used/applied at the same time). For many/most code pages and for UTF-8/UTF-16 as well, the character-onto-codepoint (latter is the bit pattern) mappings are identical to ASCII. If your characters are within the first/lower 7 bits of the byte, it does not matter what the encoding theoretically would be, as the 8th bit is not used for any of code pages or UTF-8. It only matters a great deal if/for characters that do have the 8th bit set/used (and usually if there's bytes like that, the choice of its encoding would usually then then for the entire file, just that some bytes may stay within the single-byte ASCII, but really should take great care at inserting/interpreting binary patterns that have the 8th bit set in a byte).

Easy rule is: if all bytes (or the byte in question) don't have the 8th bit set, it only matters whether the lower 7 bits are ASCII or not. EBCDIC for example is a non-ASCII alternative, where dec 26 hex 1A is UBS (unit backspace), while it also does have a SUB (substitute) but it's on codepoint (binary pattern) dec 63 hex 3F. Other encodings may not have ASCII's SUB at all, or something similar but with a slightly different meaning/use, or maybe ASCII has it's SUB from EBCDIC, etc. But there's no need to wonder/worry about UTF-8, as it does not apply if ASCII can be assumed, for the characters as encoded in ASCII are encoded identically UTF-8 as a single byte with the highest bit not set.

Maybe it can be determined from the spec if all the characters mentioned are within the ASCII range and according to the ASCII codepoint definitions, or if there's other characters that might only be found in UTF-8 (or UTF-16 or UTF-32) or in one of the old extended code pages (but not found in others), or if there's any indication that the encoding might not be ASCII/ASCII-based.

It's obviously problematic if a spec doesn't explicitly state the encoding it's implicitly assuming, if the spec is about a format, protocol or data representation. On the other hand, maybe the Ctrl-Z is misleading, because dec 26 hex 1A is always the same, no matter what the encoding could be if it were text/characters. Maybe the spec just uses this pattern as a construct with no meaning in terms of character display whatsoever, and is introducing only it's own particular local meaning as defined within the spec.